UK Standard Visitor visa - Where should I upload letters explaining specific deposits in my bank account?
I am a permanent resident of Canada applying for a UK Standard Visitor visa and currently in the process of uploading the supporting documents on the VFS website. I am currently employed full-time, which means that I have regular source of income in form of my salary.
Earlier this year I received a deposit in my bank account from the tax agency, sometime after I submitted my income tax report. The deposit is shown in my bank statement. I also have the letter from the tax agency regarding this. I understand that any deposit should be explained. In this case, where should I upload the letter? Under Financial Evidence section where the I upload the bank statements, or Additional Documents/Others?
Thanks in advance

I doubt it matters, however personally I’d upload it in the Financial Evidence section.

Not any deposit, but everything outside normal. So, it it is a large amount compared to what you have in the account: yes, explain it.
